# Considering MySQL on SSD with NTFS and Windows 2008

Tags: windows, mysql, ntfs, ssd

My company is considering migrating our MySQL data from an HDD array to an SSD, possibly the Intel SSD 520 series. We have a fairly large set of databases, some with upwards of 100 million rows, so we are looking for some performance gains. I have done some research and have found quite a bit of info about MySQL on SSD's with Linux & EXT3/EXT4 but not so much with Windows & NTFS. Has anyone had any experience using MySQL on an SSD with Windows 2008 & NTFS? Any tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are the databases currently running on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Apologize if I wasn't clear. We are currently running MySQL on Windows 2008 with an HDD array and are considering moving the MySQL data to an SSD.

Comment: When you say array, are you just talking about a local RAID array, a DASD or a SAN? How big are the databases in GB?

Comment: Local RAID array, all databases together about 250GB, which is several DB's in the 60 - 80GB range.

Comment: I don't have enough experience with MySQL to provide a lot of help on this question, my only suggestion is that I would imagine a lot of the MSSQL technical articles relating to SSD usage would be relavent, albeit not precise.  They both work in similar ways to some extent so a lot of the performance pitfalls with MSSQL on SSDs and vice versa are probably still relevant to your question.